# query that returns average of records within range of timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have the following columns.

```
-READING_DATE               timestamp - in '01-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM' format    


-DISCHARGE_M3PERSEC           number
```

How can I have the average daily discharge per day for a range of dates (until march) including the first day (Jan 1st) to last day (March 13).

Additionally, I also need to find hourly average and monthly averages.

Thanks.

--- update: the following query results in an error ORA-01855 AM or PM required.

```
SELECT TRUNC(READING_DATE) AS READING_DATE,
  AVG(DISCHARGE_M3PERSEC) AS DISCHARGE
  FROM HYDROMETRIC_GUELPH
  WHERE READING_DATE 
    BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('01-JAN-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SSxFF AM') 
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP('13-MAR-16 05.30.00.00.000000000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SSxFF PM')
GROUP BY TRUNC(READING_DATE);
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: See the update above

Comment: Could this be revelant?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664231/ora-01855-am-a-m-or-pm-p-m-required

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33916272/2055998) applies.

Comment: I have tried what they are suggesting but it is not the same issue. I think mine is with the timestamp and the format to get the daily averages.

Answer (score 0):

The query runs fine, you just have a silly typo in the TO_TIMESTAMP. You have the hour 05, minutes 30, then you have the 00 group TWICE (for seconds?) Just delete the second group and its period (00.) from TO_TIMESTAMP and you have your query. Please write back if you need further help.

Comment: unfortunately the same error occurs as the data is in that format

Comment: Not sure you understand. It should be: 05.30.00.000000. Instead you have an EXTRA 00.  like so:  05.30.00.00.000000. You have FIVE groups of digits separated by FOUR periods, instead of four groups separated by three periods.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps do not have a format. You can use ANSI timestamp literals to avoid any formatting and language/locale issues:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(READING_DATE) AS READING_DATE,
        AVG(DISCHARGE_M3PERSEC) AS DISCHARGE
FROM    HYDROMETRIC_GUELPH
WHERE   READING_DATE  BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                      AND     TIMESTAMP '2016-03-13 17:30:00.000'
GROUP BY TRUNC(READING_DATE);
```